# Openshift Monitoring - cAdvisor + Prometheus - Docker

Tags: docker, openshift, prometheus, cadvisor, redhat-containers

I tried to implement a monitoring solution for Openshift cluster based on Prometheus + node-exporter + grafana + cAdvisor.

I have a huge problem with cAdvisor component. I did a lot of configuration (The changes always do with volumes), but none of them work well, containter restarting every ~2min or do not collect all data metrics (processes)

example of configuration(with this config containter do not restart every 2min, but not collect processes) I know, i dont have /rootfs in volumes, but with this container work like 5s and goes down:

```
containers:
    - image: >-
        google/cadvisor@sha256:fce642268068eba88c27c666e92ed4144be6188447a23825015884741cf0e352
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: cadvisor-new-version
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      resources: {}
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct,cpu'
          name: sys
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/lib/docker
          name: docker
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
          name: docker-socketd
          readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: cadvisor-sa
  serviceAccountName: cadvisor-sa
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct'
      name: sys
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/docker
      name: docker
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
      name: docker-socketd
```

i use a service account in my OS project with scc-privileged.

- Openshift version - 3.6
- Docker version - 1.12
- cAdvisor version - I tried every one from v0.26.3 to newest

**I found a post that the problem can be the old version od docker, can anyone confirmed this?**

**Maybe someone do the right configuration and implement cAdvisor on Openshift?**

---

example of logs:

```
I0409 08:41:46.661453       1 manager.go:231] Version: 
 {KernelVersion:3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 ContainerOsVersion:Alpine Linux v3.4 DockerVersion:1.12.6 DockerAPIVersion:1.24 CadvisorVersion:v0.28.3 CadvisorRevision:1e567c2}
E0409 08:41:50.823560       1 factory.go:340] devicemapper filesystem stats will not be reported: usage of thin_ls is disabled to preserve iops
I0409 08:41:50.825280       1 factory.go:356] Registering Docker factory
I0409 08:41:50.826394       1 factory.go:54] Registering systemd factory
I0409 08:41:50.826949       1 factory.go:86] Registering Raw factory
I0409 08:41:50.827388       1 manager.go:1178] Started watching for new ooms in manager
I0409 08:41:50.838169       1 manager.go:329] Starting recovery of all containers
W0409 08:41:56.853821       1 container.go:393] Failed to create summary reader for "/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-podc323db44_39a9_11e8_accd_005056800e7b.slice/docker-26db795af0fa28047f04194d8169cf0249edf2c918c583422a1404d35ed5b62c.scope": none of the resources are being tracked.
I0409 08:42:03.953261       1 manager.go:334] Recovery completed
I0409 08:42:37.874062       1 cadvisor.go:162] Starting cAdvisor version: v0.28.3-1e567c2 on port 8080
I0409 08:42:56.353574       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.20076874s: [ /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/2afa2c457a9c1769feb6ab542102521d8ad51bdeeb89581e4b7166c1c93e7522]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
I0409 08:42:56.453602       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.098795382s: [ /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/65e4ad3536788b289e2b9a29e8f19c66772b6f38ec10d34a2922e4ef4d67337f]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
I0409 08:42:56.753070       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.400184357s: [ /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/2b0aa12a43800974298a7d0353c6b142075d70776222196c92881cc7c7c1a804]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
I0409 08:43:00.352908       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.199079344s: [ /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/aa977c2cc6105e633369f48e2341a6363ce836cfbe8e7821af955cb0cf4d5f26]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
```

Comment: Add is there anything from the logs you can share since you say it does work for 5s before it then exits out?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, example of logs in post.

Answer (score 1):

There's a cAdvisor process embedded in the OpenShift's kubelet. Maybe there's a race condition that makes the pod crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing something similar in a three node docker swarm where cadvisor on one node - and only that one - keeps dying after a few minutes. I've watched the process and looked at it's resource usage - it's running out of memory.

I've set a 128MB limit but I've tried higher limits as well. It just buys it more time but even at 500MB it soon died because it ran out of memory.

The only thing that seems to be abnormal are those same "du and find on following dirs took" messages:

```
I0515 15:14:37.109399       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 46.19060577s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/69a2bd344a635cde23e6c27a69c165ed001178a9093964d73bebdbb81d90369b /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/6fd8113e383f78e20608be807a38e17b14715636b94aa99112dd6d7208764a2e]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 5s
I0515 15:14:35.511417       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 58.306835696s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/bed9b7ad307f36ae97659b79912ff081f5b64fb8d57d6a48f143cd3bf9823e64 /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/108f4b879f7626023be8790af33ad6b73189a27e7c9bb7d6f219521d43099bbe]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 5s
I0515 15:14:47.513604       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 45.911742867s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/c9989697f40789a69be47511c2b931f8949323d144051912206fe719f12e127d /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/4cd1baa15522b58f61e9968c1616faa426fb3dfd9ac8515896dcc1ec7a0cb932]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 5s
I0515 15:14:49.210788       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 46.406268577s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/7605c354c073800dcbb14df16da4847da3d70107509d27f8f1675aab475eb0df /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/00f37c6569bb29c028a90118cf9d12333907553396a95390d925a4c2502ab058]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 5s
I0515 15:14:45.614715       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1m1.573576904s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/62d99773c5d1be97863f90b5be03eb94a4102db4498931863fa3f5c677a06a06 /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/bf3e2d8422cda2ad2bcb433e30b6a06f1c67c3a9ce396028cdd41cce3b0ad5d6]; will not log again for this container unless duration exceeds 5s
```

What's interesting is that it starts out taking only a couple of seconds:

```
I0515 15:09:48.710609       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.496309475s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/a11190ca4731bbe6d9cbe1a2480e781490dc4e0e6c91c404bc33d37d7d251564 /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/d0b45858ae55b6613c4ecabd8d44e815c898bbb5ac5c613af52d6c1f4804df76]; will not log a
gain for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
I0515 15:09:49.909390       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.29921035s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/62d99773c5d1be97863f90b5be03eb94a4102db4498931863fa3f5c677a06a06 /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/bf3e2d8422cda2ad2bcb433e30b6a06f1c67c3a9ce396028cdd41cce3b0ad5d6]; will not log ag
ain for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
I0515 15:09:51.014721       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 1.502355544s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/5264e7a8c3bfb2a4ee491d6e42e41b3300acbcf364455698ab232c1fc9e8ab4e /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/da355f40535a001c5ba0e16da61b6340028b4e432e0b2f14b8949637559ff001]; will not log a
gain for this container unless duration exceeds 2s
I0515 15:09:53.309486       1 fsHandler.go:135] du and find on following dirs took 2.19038347s: [/rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/8b0fd9287d107580b76354851b75c09ce47e114a70092305d42f8c2b5f5e23b2 /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/5fd8ac9fd8d98d402851f2642266ca89598a964f50cfabea9bdf50b87f7cff66]; will not log ag
```

So something seems to be getting progressively worse until the container dies.